# Why does pod spec lint fail for zip file hosted on private GitHub repository?

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to create a Podspec for a binary XCFramework of an iOS library that is hosted in a private repository on GitHub. I want CocoaPods `pod install` to be able to download the zip from a GitHub release with a specific version number.

However, `pod spec lint` fails for my pod which is published to a private repository.

It appears that this may be a limitation of GitHub itself, but I've raised the [issue on the cocoa pods GitHub page](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12036) in the hope that someone can correct me, or at least confirm that it's a GitHub limitation, or provide a workaround .

I haven't received any replies to my Issue on GitHub. Does anyone here have any experience with this?